# how to install kivy

Tags: python, pip, kivy

I am currently on python-3.9 (I dont know whether it is supported by kivy if not please let me know how which version is supported by kivy) I bascially ran

`pip install kivy`

and ran into errors
[image]

and dont know what to know.
I installed all dependencies for kivy needed and what should i do know??

TQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read the instructions from the kivy documentation clearly, https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html. if you are using pip for installing. please do read about the manual installation of dependencies. I suggest you to use conda prompt (Anaconda Navigator) the first section of documentation or the command below will be enough

```
conda install kivy -c conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install kivy
```

`Pipwin` has unofficial packages compiled for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with below instructions** Installed on windows 10

1. python -m virtualenv kivy_venv
2. kivy_venv\Scripts\activate
3. python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv
4. python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.3.1  kivy_deps.glew==0.3.0
5. python -m pip install kivy_deps.angle==0.3.0
6. pip install pipwin
   7.python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
7. python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
8. python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
9. python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
10. pip install pipwin
11. pipwin install kivy==1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

at this moment up to Python 3.7 is supported

[Kivy home page](https://kivy.org/#home)

I use Kivy 1.11 on Windows and Linux with Python 3.7

Kivy installation is pretty difficult so I don't recommend using the newer Python versions as there are relatively few changes above Python 3.7